# why this pattern=”^re\-\d{6}$" not working properly in html

Tags: html

it's not giving me error message when I input different pattern, what did I do wrong ?

```
<label for="receipt">Receipt number *</label>
            <input name="receipt" id="receipt" 
                    placeholder="re-nnnnnn" required="required" 
                    pattern="^re\-\d{6}$" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. For example, if your goal is `re-123456`, you should remove the first back-slash.

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="receipt">Receipt number *</label>
  <input name="receipt" id="receipt" placeholder="re-nnnnnn" required="required" pattern="^re-\d{6}$" />
</form>
```